# Pandas x-ticks plot not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Trying to plot a graph and set x ticks but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
postcodes = ['6000', '6003', '6005', '6006', '6007', '6008', '6009', '6010', '6011', '6012']
ax4 = data9310.plot(title='Population 2011/2016')
ax4.set_xticklabels(postcodes, rotation=0)
```

Result:

[image: It's only showing 6003-6008]

6003 is in 6000 spot and so on... so each point should have one of the postcodes on the x axis

Comment: Your ticks are strings, and uneven. Is that intentional?

Comment: No, uneven is not intentional I'll fix that. I've used strings before and it has worked.

Comment: Could you post some of your data and its overall length, please? Difficult to reproduce error without it.

Comment: I'm extracting values off a CSV via slicing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graph labels all major x-ticks that have been automatically created by `matplotlib`. You can specify the x-ticks that are set:

```
#create random test data
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100, (10, 3)), columns = list("ABC"))
#your plot
postcodes = ['6000', '6003', '6005', '6006', '6007', '6008', '6009', '6010', '6011', '6012']
ax4 = data.plot(title='Population 2011/2016')
#specify that every n-th x-tick is shown, in case that with n = 1 the axis is too crowded
n = 2
#set x-ticks
ax4.set_xticks(np.arange(0, len(postcodes), n))
#label them according to your list
ax4.set_xticklabels(postcodes[::n], rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]